# error when i am trying the set a path on routes file (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i have an app with a SearchController and index action. 
on the views i have index.html.erb and in the file i wrote this code:

```
<h1>Search#index</h1>
<%= form_tag(search_path, :method => "get") do %>
  <%= label_tag(:q, "Search for:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:q) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
<% end %>
```

and my routes file is this:

```
Ti::Application.routes.draw do
  get "search/index"
  root :to => "search#index"
end
```

when i runed the app i got a error that i did not set the "search path" on the routes file so i added this line:

```
map.search "search", :controller => "search"
```

but that line dont work, what shoud i write ?

10x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
match 'search', :to => 'search#index'
```

And don't be afraid to have a play in your routes.rb file. I'd really recommend spending a couple of hours adding dummy routes and running:

```
rake routes
```

and see what comes out the other end. If you're just starting out with routes in Rails 3 you should check out this page, it's a pretty good starting point.

http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2010/the-lowdown-on-routes-in-rails-3/